# IBM Watson Speech to Text and webm

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Currently IBM Watson Speech to Text service supports only “ogg” compressed format. However, a new standard for WebRTC platform is “webm”. As a result, we have to either use Firefox or send huge “wav” files without compression to Bluemix from a client browser. Is it possible to make support of “webm”?

Comment: Hello slav, currently we do not support webm. What is your use case? Do you plan to send lots of audio to Watson STT? lets open a discussion

Comment: @slav - If you have suggestions for improvements to the Bluemix platform, feel free to post it on the IBM Bluemix Ideas site, which is available at this URL: https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas

Comment: @billwentworth Thank you Bill. I did not know about this forum, I will use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service added support for `webm` on April 10th, 2017. See the [release notes](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/release-notes.html#release-notes). Additionally, here is a list of the [audio formats](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/audio-formats.html#formats) supported by the service.

Comment: hi @germanAttanasio can you help me in integration of IBM watson with twilio